# Polars DataFrame memory size in Python

Tags: python, memory, python-polars

Was wondering about the size of particular polars DataFrames.
I tried with:

```
from sys import getsizeof

getsizeof(df)
Out[17]: 48
getsizeof(df.to_pandas())
Out[18]: 1602923950
```

It appears all polars df are 48 bytes? Confused.

Answer (score 14):

Using the `polars.DataFrame.estimated_size()` method we can get the size of the dataframe similar to `pandas.info()`.

Follow the [link](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/dataframe/api/polars.DataFrame.estimated_size.html).

Answer (score 7):

The Python package `polars` is only a wrapper for the underlying core `polars` library written in Rust. So I'm pretty sure what you're seeing when you call `getsizeof` on the `DataFrame` is the `getsizeof` result for the Python object implementing that type in the `polars` Python package (at the wrapper layer).

With `pandas` the `df.info()` function will include memory usage. I was actually looking for this in `polars` as well.

I noticed there are individual functions for getting the null count and the schema ([#2492](https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/issues/2429)), but I couldn't track down a way to print a `DataFrame`'s memory usage from a `polars` implementation.

I'll bump this question in the discord. This should be doable to implement if I'm not over-simplifying it.

Comment: Potter420 on the discord server reminded me of a great point. The underlying `arrow` format (`arrow2` here) would make it difficult to do this with complete accuracy but this topic does have visibility it seems https://github.com/jorgecarleitao/arrow2/issues/421

Comment: I've submitted an issue for this https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/issues/3106